# Blowing up of $xz = y^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y = V(xz - y^2)$ in $\mathbb A^3$. Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be the blowing up of $Y$ at the origin and $E$ is the exceptional divisor. Then

1. How to see $E \cong \mathbb P^1$ and $X$ is smooth?
2. How to show $E^2 = -2$?

Edit:

My attempt is to do direct calculations: Let $F:\mathbb A^3\times\mathbb P^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb A^3$ be the projection $(x,y,z,r,s,t)\mapsto (x,y,z)$. Then the $X$ is given by the equation $y^2 = xz$ and $\frac{x}{r} = \frac ys = \frac zt$. But I don't know how to write down the equation for $E$ and compute $E^2$.

Edit 2:

The affine open subset $U = D(t)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^5$. Then $U\cap X$ is given by $y^2 = xz$, $x = rz$ and $y = st$. It seems to isomorphic to $(sz)^2 = (rz)z$ or $z^2(s^2-r) = 0$ in $\mathbb A^3$? The exceptional divisor is given by $x=y=z=0$ which means $(r,s,t)$ can be arbitrary point in $\mathbb P^2$. In $U$ with affine coordinates $(s,t,z)$, it is $z = 0$. But isn't $z = 0$ a plane rather than a line?

Comment: This question is pretty low on context at the moment. Your question would be markedly improved by adding any of the following information: what you know about computing blowups, what you have tried here, where you are stuck, etc.

Comment: Remember that $r,s,t$ are homogeneous coordinates. What do you get in each of the three affine patches on $\Bbb P^2$? What is the meaning of “the exceptional divisor”? Continue to edit.

Comment: You've computed the total transform of $Y$ in the blowup of $\Bbb A^3$ at the origin. To compute the blowup of $Y$ in the origin, you need to take the *strict transform* of $Y$ in the blowup of $\Bbb A^3$ at the origin.

Comment: @KReiser Can I say the strict transform is $s^2 - r = 0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Is there any way to see the self-intersection $E^2 = -2$?

Comment: One reason we ask you to show your attempts is that it's very hard to guess what notation and concepts you are familiar with. For example, what is the normal bundle of the exceptional divisor in the ambient blow up $\widetilde{\Bbb A^3}$? What is the restriction of that bundle to the conic $E\subset\Bbb P^2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I don't know how to represent the normal bundle of $E$ in $\tilde{A}^3$.

Comment: Sheafically, it is $\mathscr O_{\Bbb P^2}(-1)$. (This is the dual of the hyperplane bundle.) This is all standard as part of the blow-up machinery. You can check it, for example, with transition functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to blow up $Y$ at the origin, it is most convenient to identify $\tilde{Y}$ which the strict transform of $Y$ under the blowup $\pi: \tilde{\mathbb{A}^3} \to \mathbb{A}^3$ along the maximal ideal $(x,y,z) \subset k[x,y,z]$. Recall that $$\tilde{\mathbb{A}^3} = \mathbb{A}^3_{u_0,u_1,z} \cup \mathbb{A}^3_{u_0,y,u_2} \cup \mathbb{A}^3_{x,u_1,u_2} \subset \mathbb{A}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^2_{u_1, u_2, u_3}$$
where under these identifications, the maps from these charts to $\mathbb{A}^3$ are defined in the usual way. (eg. in the first chart $\pi^*x = u_0z, \pi^*y = u_1z, \pi^* z = z$) In these charts, the exceptional divisor $F$ of $\tilde{\mathbb{A}^3}$ is cut out by $(z)$, $(y)$, and $(x)$ respectively. (We can see this by considering the extension ideal $(\pi^*x, \pi^*y, \pi^*z)$ of $(x,y,z)$ in each of the charts.)

To get the strict transform of $Y$ in these charts, we just need to factor the exceptional locus out of $\pi^*(xz - y^2)$. This will give the following equations for $\tilde{Y}$.

$$\{u_0 - u_1^2, u_0u_2 - 1, u_2 - u_1^2\}$$

The jacobian criterion then implies $\tilde{Y}$ will be smooth. Moreover, we see from the above that the exceptional divisor $E$ of $\tilde{Y}$ is identified with the conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$, so it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

**Remark:** Notice that none of the equations above include the original variables. This reflects the fact that since $Y$ is an affine cone, its blowup becomes an affine bundle over the exceptional divisor $E$.

If we view $Y$ as a divisor on $\mathbb{A}^3$, the above computation implies $\pi^*Y = \tilde{Y} + 2F$. Since $F|_{\tilde{Y}} = E$ it follows that $E^2 = F^2.\tilde{Y}$. By the projection formula, $\pi^*Y.F^2 = Y.(\pi_*F)^2 = 0$. Hence, $$F^2.\tilde{Y} = -2F^3 = -2.$$

To get $F^3 = 1$, we use that the normal bundle of $F$ in $\tilde{\mathbb{A}^3}$ is identified with $\mathcal{O}_F(-1)$ where we consider $F \cong \mathbb{P}^2$. (cf. Hartshorne II.8.24(c)) This implies that $\mathcal{N}_{F/\tilde{\mathbb{A}}} = \mathcal{O}(F)|_{F}\cong \mathcal{O}_F(-1)$. It follows that $$F^3 = (F|_F)^2 = c_1(\mathcal{O}(F)|_{F})^2 = c_1(\mathcal{O}_F(-1))^2 = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Could you explain more about the remark? How to see the blowup is an affine bundle over $E$?

Comment: I think that should be $\pi^*Y=\tilde{Y}+2F$ and $\pi^*Y.F^2=0$ instead $E$.

Comment: @Hydrogen Sorry for the late reply. The idea is to restrict the projection onto $\mathbb{P}^2$. In the first chart, the $z$ variable is free, so this projection gives an isomorphism $\tilde{Y}|_{\mathbb{A}^1_{u_0, u_1, z}} \cong Z_{\mathbb{A}^2}(u_0 - u_1^2) \times \mathbb{A}^1_{z}.$ The other charts are analogous. The general fact that cones are resolved into bundles can also be justified algebraically as in Hartshorne's example V.2.11.4.

Comment: @user426214 That's right; thank you. I'll edit the fix in.